# How to calculate $\text{Ext}(M,N)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I am confused about the calculation of $\text{Ext}(M,N)$. If $N$ is a fixed module and if we consider a projective resolution
$$\cdots \to C_1 \to C_0 \to M \to 0,$$ then $\text{Ext}^n(M,N)$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ homology of
$$0 \to \text{Hom}(C_0,N) \to \text{Hom}(C_1,N)\to \cdots$$
Since the $\text{Hom}$ functor is left exact, we have

$$0 \to \text{Hom}(M,N) \to \text{Hom}(C_0,N) \to \text{Hom}(C_1,N)\to\cdots  \to \text{Hom}(C_{n+1},N)$$ is exact (is this true?) so clearly $$\text{Ext}^0(M,N) = \text{Hom}(M,N),$$

but since the above sequence is exact, does this imply that $\text{Ext}^1(M,N)=0\,$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the meaning of left exactness. The indicated complex of $\mathrm{Hom}$-modules is not exact.

Comment: Hi @Lms, you may want to learn about tex for your next post. Also, any thoughts about why you think this might hold and work you have done so far would help people give better answers

Comment: How is the left exactness working with an infinite sequence for a contravariant functor?

Comment: Here is an example which may help you see your error.  Take the ring to be $A=k[x]/x^2$ and $M=N=k$ with $x$ acting as zero (except $C_0 \to k$).  Take the resolution to be $C_i=A$ with all maps multiplication by $x$. Then the complex of homs is not exact, indeed the induced maps are zero and every ext group is one-dimensional.

Comment: So, left exactness can only apply on short exact sequences, not long exact sequences

Comment: Well, exactness is preserved on an exact sequence $0\to A\to B \to C$ or $C\to B\to A\to 0$ (to be precise, exact on $A$ and $B$), depending on which Hom-functor you use.  The point of left/right-exactness is precisely that it doesn't preserve exactness when you have a complex longer than that.

Comment: Also, just a side notes (a concern when I read the complexes you written), be careful when you calculate Ext's.  You have projective resolution $P_M^\bullet\to M \to 0$, but when you calculate Ext-groups, you are taking homology on the complex $\text{Hom}(P_M^\bullet,N)$, i.e. $M$ is excluded in the complex. So $\text{Ext}^0(M,N) = H^0(Hom(P_M^\bullet,N)) \simeq Hom(M,N)$.

Comment: Correct. Left/right exactness only applies to short exact sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $Hom$ functor is left exact but *NOT* exact. So it is not true that the above complex is exact, it's only a *complex*. 
your idea about the equality of "ext" and "hom" at point $0$ is correct because of "left exactness".
In fact it is exact till $0 \to \text{Hom}(M,N) \to \text{Hom}(C_0,N) \to \text{Hom}(C_1,N)$.